# selenium webdriver audio grant allow

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to allow audio grant
with using chrome_option method
in python code

so I tried

```py
chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream")
```

but It is not working .....

my code is below

```
from selenium import webdriver

# 웹 드라이버 초기화

# 원하는 창 크기로 설정 (가로 너비 x 세로 높이)
width = 800
height = 600

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

# not working
chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(width, height)
# 웹 브라우저 열기

driver.get("http://localhost:8080/api/player")


# 웹 브라우저를 사용한 작업 수행

# 웹 드라이버 종료
# driver.quit()
```

Comment: I Finded a way to play
chrome_options.add_argument("--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required")
add that!!!!!
wow Thanks Chrome Dev!!!!